# How can I improve my first question?

Tags: support, new-users, question-quality

I have a question about my Super User post: [How to create a PXEboot for tails OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1772635/how-to-create-a-pxeboot-for-tails-os)

I'm new to this site I find very helpful and of very good quality.

How can I improve my first posted question?

Comment: Why do you think you need to improve your question?

Comment: Its got all the constraints, lets someone trying to resolve the problem know about your environment constraints. What files, what PXE boot server and its config might be usefull I guess?

Comment: @Ramhound, feedback is important, particularly when new.

Comment: @AlexVal - Feedback requires there to be something wrong with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This meta question was posted just 9 hours after the question on the main site was posted. This make me think that your motiviatio to ask for guidance about how to improve your questions comes from not having at that time any vote or comment.

Here is your answer: **please be patient**.

Yes. It's is not what you was expecting, I know. Please bear in mind that one of the things that is required to communtiy members is to be open to getting an answer that is not what they are expecting.

In the meantime that your question gets an answer, a vote or a comment, additionally to improving this meta question, i.e. share what you found in this Meta site and in the [Help Center](https://meta.superuser.com/help) and why it didn't meet your needs your might follow the [tour](https://meta.superuser.com/tour) to learn the pretty basics about how this site works (including earn your first badge, if you haven't earned yet) and getting ideas about how to earn 20 reputation points to participate in the chat as well to earn other privileges.

Regarding the time get an answer, if you like data and statistics you might get a lot of them here, but unfortunatelly we can't promise when your question will get an answer. Some good questions never get an answer simple **because nobody knows it!**

---

I'm unfamiliar with the tags of your question. On the the tags that I participate almost all of them are about stuff having official resources (aka manual / documentation) and most of them are available on the Web. Many of my comments suggests to *googling* the official resources, add what was found and why it didn't meet the OP needs some times I *google* myself and one way or another share what I found, specially because even repeating exactly the same steps later the results could not be the same.

In the case of your question I don't have idea if *googling* make sense.

References:

- [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)